# how can prove the date I came back to US

Tags: us-citizens

I'm US citizen.Social Security Office asked me to prove I did come back to US on time because I get SSI(Supplementary Security Income), I can't go abroad over 30 days.US customs didn't stamp on my passport.How can I prove to Social Security Office?  Peter Doan

Comment: If you refer to the time you asked this question last week, you'll find some suggestions. They're looking for copies of the plane ticket, signed statements from people who know where you were, and other documents that demonstrate when you returned to the US. Credit card/bank receipts could also be useful.